# How can i find out the caller of some thread in visual studio (c++)?

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio

Let's assume...

ClassA::caller() makes an instance of ThreadA and start this thread.

and after that...

if i pause the process with visual studio, and look at the Stack-Trace Window of ThreadA, 
then i can not find out who the caller is.

In this case, ClassA::caller() is the caller.

Is there any way to find out the caller of some Threads in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

"ClassA::caller() is the caller" -- I'm afraid that you have a misconception about the operation of threads. In particular, calling this code that created the thread "caller" is not really helpful. This function is just one function that was called and which then caused the creation of another thread. Apart from this short rendezvous, there is no connection between a thread and the code where it is started.

Why do you care? What is it that you want to know? Also, it could be helpful if you mentioned which language you are using.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i am using c++ with vs2008 pro (non managed c++). Why i am care of the caller? Because ThreadA is used(created and launched) in many different places in my code. and if some trouble occurs in ThreadA at some moment, i want to find out which one created this thread and launched it.

Comment: Maybe there is a different way to think about it that would light a different way. When a thread is started, there is no connection maintained between the starting thread and the started thread. The only thing that you have is the data that you pass to the started thread via e.g. its context pointer, and typically all you need is in this data or global. In this context you can also store additional info that tells you from where you started this thread, if you want. BTW: You can't start the same thread more than once. You can only start multiple threads with the same function or data!

Comment: thank you again. i just wanted to know if any possiblity exist in vs 2008, because vs 2008 knows as Debugger all situation; who launched which threads, etc. if there is no such functionality in vs, then i should put the caller-information in each callee thread. Which i did not want to.. thank you anyways.